# PHP artisan Not Responding In Terminal

Tags: php, terminal, cpanel, laravel-artisan

[image]

Hi guys, my name is Max. So the question is that php artisan is not responding in the cPanel terminal. The project is deployed already through Bluehost. The goal is run php artisan migration, but the situation is any other commands works for me only except anything that includes php artisan. At first I thought it was the artisan file issue but I have checked the artisan and it doesn't have issue appearing to me. And the command is indeed ran under the root project directory.

Please Help me, I have searched online and I haven't seen many solution to the issue yet.

1. Tried composer self-upgrade and there is version control restrictions
2. Tried php artisan version and no responding
3. Tried modification of artisan file nothing shows if its related to php artisan
4. Changing Directory of the project shows no artisan which recognizes commands

Comment: You might try "php -v" first to figure out if PHP is working correctly